# Serving and testing a bundle after ng build

Tags: angular-cli

After I build a bundle with `ng build --prod --aot` I would like to quickly serve it locally. Is there a way to quickly serve the `/dist` directory locally using @angular/cli?

I tried to `cd dist && ng serve` but the `dist` disappears when the `ng serve` command is run.

Comment: Do you just want to serve dist folder locally for testing and development? Or do you need to serve it for production?

Comment: Just for testing, a quick local test of integrity, FWIW

Comment: ah, then just do `ng serve --prod --aot`. OR if you want to test with a stand alone node server you can use `http-server` https://github.com/indexzero/http-server. the documentation is straight forward.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`http-server` is what I use, and it works well.

Install:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

`cd` into your dist folder, type `http-server`, then enter. Or, just do `http-server .\dist` at the command line after your application build is successful.

Open a browser, and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

More info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

I use this on all my dev machines for running built ng applications.

Or, was there more than simply seeing if the application runs (smoke test) that you were looking for in this?

Comment: With latest `npm` and `Angular CLI v7+`: Use `npm install http-server --save-dev`, `cd dist/<project-name>`, `npx http-server`

Comment: what is difference between http-server and angular-http-server.

Comment: While this works, the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60219009/1101602) doesn't require you to install any new packages.

Answer (score 6):

Following did the trick for us:

```
ng serve --configuration production
```

If running the Angular development server that way the production configuration is used and you can observe the results.

We also encountered that when building the application for production the **--prod** flag was not enough we needed to explicitly set the **--configuration** option to **production** for referencing the correct configuration files.:

```
ng build --configuration production
```

Answer (score 5):

to test easily built angular app I use this `angular-http-server`

to install it you can do

```
npm install -g angular-http-server
cd /path/to/site/dist/site
angular-http-server
```

if you need more info you can check the package npm page [angular-http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server)