# Angular 6 Application how to serve it locally on wamp and how to import missing files into index page

Tags: php, angular, wamp, angular6, wampserver

**EDIT #2**

On my `www/` directory, I have my server scripts and the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ api.php [L]
DirectoryIndex api.php

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !echo.php
#RewriteRule .* echo.php?ua=%{HTTP_USER_AGENT}&https=%{HTTPS} [L]

SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(dev.local\.com|localhost:8100|localhost:4200)$" ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ORIGIN}e env=ORIGIN
Header merge Vary Origin

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, cookie"
Header set Content-Type "application/json"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST"
# prevent mime based attacks
Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
```

On my desktop, I have the the angular project where I run:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

I got a folder inside, called `dist/angular/` and inside of it, all the related files.

I took the `dist/angular/` content and place it in `www/` directory and tried to run the `index.html` file, and got the following errors:

[image]

I finished an application for my organization, based on angular 6 and PHP as server side, and I need to test it locally. Most of our works, will be made locally, as the boss don't want any information to go over the wire (NGO data).

I ran:

`ng-build --prod`

And I've got the `dist` folder. But I opened the dist folder, and can't know what to do, and how to put it on wampserver to let users test it from their computers.

I checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656895/serving-and-testing-a-bundle-after-ng-build) with its selected answer about adding `http-server`.

Does working with `http-server` will be good option when using wampserver as local server to serve our app ?

Edit:

When I open my index.html file, I got 5 errors:

[image]

`index.html` script:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Registration System</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->

  <!--Bootstrap 4-->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.aa5ea5c31cd0cd659c6e.css"></head> 
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.2b56e49bc4acc7387a7f.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.6a1700e5ae732a3a8f93.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.35b38c7c508a8567ed23.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can run `ng build`, then you can run `ng serve`. Did you try using it ?

Comment: No I didn't because I need to make it work using wamp.

Comment: @trichetriche check my edit

Comment: Why would you have to use wamp if you only run it locally ? (I'm just getting intel before answering you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and it was that I didn't add the built files inside server folder (in my case the `www` directory), and it should be accessed through the link:

`localhost/yourfolder/` and not by just clicking on the `index.html` file.

Here is my final `.htaccess` that has been added within the `dist` folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

And at the index.html, I left it as `<base href="/">`

Answer (score 5):

When hosting an Angular app, you can literally just take the content of the `dist` folder and place it in your `htdocs` or `www` folder. Well, in the simplest scenario at least.

There are a few caveats though.

The above works well when you want to serve it by itself, in the root of your server.

If you are hosting the Angular app from a sub-folder, you will need to change the base URL of the app by changing this line in the index.html file:

```
<base href="/path/to/folder/">
```

Also, if you haven't yet, you need to correctly configure [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for the PHP backend.

Finally, you need to take care of routing. This requires entries in the `.htaccess` file to route as follows:

1. Any path that should go to the Angular app must route to its `index.html`.
2. All JavaScript, CSS, font and image files should route as normal.
3. The PHP files should still route as normal, preferably to a subfolder to keep things clean. I like to use `/api` for this.

As an example, I have a PHP backend, that is located in the `/api` folder and an Angular app that I serve from the root.

So on my server, in the `www` folder, I have my `index.html` and the various JavaScrpit files. The PHP files are under `www/api` and the `.htaccess` routing takes care of routing all API calls to `/www/api`, all JavaScript, images, fonts and styles to just where they are, and every other path to `/www/index.html`.

That's about the gist of it. As long as `.htaccess` and your CORS setup is correct, you should have no issues.

**Edit**

Based on your update showing the 404 errors, I'd say your major issue is routing in `.htaccess`. Look up URL rewriting for Apache.

**Edit**

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46009107/127826) shows a simple `.htaccess` setup that should probably work if you install in the root of your website. Even if it isn't complete for you, it's a good place to start.

Comment: I will edit my question with full details. please wait for 5 minutes and check it. your answer helped, but still not working.

Comment: @alim1990 There are a few things that seem strange. Please update your question to more clearly indicate: (1) The location of our `index.html` and JavaScript files relative to `/www`, (2) Is `api.php` the only PHP file, and could this change in the future? I ask in part because it looks like the path of your `index.html` is `/www/angular/index.html`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing :

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="./">
```

so the paths are relative to the current directory rather than relative to the root directory

Comment: how about removing `<base href="/">` ?

Comment: I got an error saying that I should add `<base href="/">`

Answer (score 1):

Heelo,

You should open your index.html and verify that everything built fine. If so you then can copy the dist directory in the `www` directory of wampserver !

Comment: open yourt browser console it surely shows errors saying that he cannot find files as vendor.js, runtme.js etc.

Comment: Is your dist folder directly in the www repertory ? If not you should use `--base-href=/my/app/`. Anyway I think this link should be usefull for you https://angular.io/guide/deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Just reference your generated js files from dist folder to you test.php page. 
Like that;

```
<script src="dist/my-app/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```